# How to get all the pictures my facebook page is tagged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page and I want to run a contest for that page I am the admin of that page. I want people to post pictures on their wall and tag my page in their picture. at the end i want to get all the pictures my page is tagged in using graph api. Is there a way to do this ?. I have tried all the things. I created a app the i got the access token with all the permissions including manage_pages. then i got the page access toke using me/accounts endpoint. then using that access token me/photos/tagged. no luck so far. I am not getting all the pictures.

A little help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Specifically: By "tagged", do you mean photos that your page is tagged in, at an x/y position, or do you mean photos where the description @mentions your page? or both. Please explain in more detail what exactly "I am not getting all the pictures" means. Which pictures are missing? Can you provide repro-steps that purposely create such a picture which is not returned as part of the `/me/photos/tagged` API call?

Comment: Thanks for replying. By tagged i mean if some one post a picture on their facebook wall and Then click on tag photo and tag my page anywhere in the picture. I am not sure what pictures I am getting because I tried tagging my page from different profiles but the results do not show up in the graph api. Before api 2.3 like a 2 or 3 weeks ago facebook documentation used to say me/photos?fields=from&type=tagged will provide me all the tagged photos

Answer (score 0):

Your question (and additional info in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540682?noredirect=1#comment47510182_29540682)) suggests that this stems from how Facebook deals with privacy. There are many scenarios in which using a page access token people cannot access content that is owned by a personal profile, even if the admin (personal profile) of the page owns that content.

If you have reason to believe that the API is not returning all the information that it should, you can [file a bug with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/). If you do, please be sure to include all the necessary steps for them to reproduce the issue or they won't be able to fix it.